# add text input at end of URL

Tags: javascript, html, href, addition

I have a simple HTML page that has a text field, a button, and a div.
I want to have a user input a stock symbol into the field. When they push submit button, an image of a graph will display inside the div.

The graphs already exist @http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/w?s=

To get a graph for a paticular symbol, I need to add the symbol, an  '&', and a large random number. This is a working example

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/w?s=YHOO&1234567890

I am not able to make the symbol, the &, and the random number append to the end of the URL.  I am also not sure if I am using form correctly.

Here is the code:

```
    function changeChart() {
    var rand_no = Math.random();
    rand_no = rand_no * 100000000;
    var sym = document.myform.symbol.value;
    document.getElementById('divService').innerHTML = '<' + 'object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/w?s="' + sym + '"&"' + rand_no + '"><\/object>';
}
```

```
<form name = "myform">
<p>
  Enter stock symbol
  <input id="Text1" type="text" name="symbol"/>
  <input type="button" value="Go" name="Submit" onclick="changeChart(this); return false;"/>
</p>

<div id="divService">
  <object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://www.aol.com/"></object>
</div>
```

Here is the complete code, The CSS wouldn't display properly on here.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pq39BKxWRqDS162jWss7-fvTbr0r28wq4VFiedh8SCY/edit?hl=en

Comment: I can see the chart with simply this: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/w?s=YHOO

Comment: True. I removed the & and the random number it worked!

Comment: The line that need to change was

Comment: document.getElementById('divService').innerHTML = '<' + 'object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/w?s=' + sym + '"><\/object>';

Answer (score 1):

I checked just some minutes ago and it seems there's no need for `&1234567890`-like part of URL, so I'd change the code to get this:

```
function changeChart() {
  var sym = document.forms[0].elements['symbol'].value;
  var divContent = '<'+'object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/w?s=' + sym +'"/>';
  document.getElementById('divService').innerHTML = divContent;
}
```

Given that random number is not necessary, and in HTML code:

```
<form name = "myform">
<p>
  Enter stock symbol
  <input id="symbol" type="text" name="symbol"/>
  <input type="button" value="Go" name="Submit" onclick="changeChart(); return false;"/>
</p>

<div id="divService">
  <object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://www.example.com/"></object>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note that now `id` has the same value as `name` for text input, and removed `this` argument for function call. I hope this helps you. (**Update**: Tested OK on jsFiddle and [here is result](http://jsfiddle.net/NyyxG/embedded/result/))

Answer (score 0):

When you make a random number using Math.random, Javascript returns a double. When you put that random number into the URL, you want it to be a string. Try changing the first line of changeChart to this:

```
var rand_no = String(Math.random() * 1000000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, no luck.